Where are the DC-3 parked at KOPF?
I recently learned that Florida Air Cargo operates three DC-3 from Miami Opa-Locka Executive Airport (KOPF).
Since I am flying into Opa-Locka this week, I would like to know where the DC-3 are parked, so I can handle my aircraft on the nearest ramp, shoot a photo and, if possible, walk around the ramp area to see them.

Google Maps knows where Florida Air Cargo ramp is:

Source. The DC-3 are not visible on the aerial view, but you can see them on Street View from the road NW of the ramp. DC-3 are apparently parked here, between the two west hangars, when not dispatched:

Source:
And ohoh... now the crew read your question and is waiting for you:

Source.

Joined just to say this - looks like you can see one off the NW145th St and NW 37ct, above the Sky Harbor Group: https://www.google.com/maps/place//@25.9077646,-80.2639384,244m
